# How to exclude the result of the specified keyword

Tags: json, swift, google-places-api

I would like to specify some keywords from the json result and exclude the result. (For example, in the image, I want to exclude two results of McDonald's of name.) I searched variously, but I do not know how to do it.

Thanks!

[json.results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfkcE.png)

```swift
for i in 0...totalHitCount - 1{
    if json["results"][i]["geometry"]["location"]["lat"] != "" &&
    json["results"][i]["geometry"]["location"]["lng"] != "" &&
    json["results"][i]["name"] != "" {
        let extractedExpr = ShopData(lat: json["results"][i]["geometry"]["location"]["lat"].double,lng:json["results"][i]["geometry"]["location"]["lng"].double,name:json["results"][i]["name"].string)
        print(json["results"][i]["name"].string)
        let shopData = extractedExpr
        self.shopDataArray.append(shopData)
        print(self.shopDataArray.debugDescription)
    }

    else{
        print("")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

To filter some names create a blacklist, the contents can be just parts of the names for example

```
let blackList = ["McDonald", "Kentucky"]
```

Then filter for

- `lat` and `long` exists
- `name` exists and is not empty
- `blacklist` does not contain `name`

  ```
  let results = json["results"].arrayValue
  for result in results {
      let location = result["geometry"]["location"]
      if let lat = location["lat"].double,
          let lng = location["lng"].double,
          let name = result["name"].string, !name.isEmpty,
          !blackList.contains(where: { name.contains($0) }) {

          let extractedExpr = ShopData(lat: lat, lng: lng, name: name)
          print(name)
          let shopData = extractedExpr
          self.shopDataArray.append(shopData)
          print(self.shopDataArray.debugDescription)

      } else {
          print(result)
      }
  }
  ```

The code is a bit *swiftier* and you are strongly encouraged to drop `SwiftyJSON` in favor of `Codable`

Comment: Thank you for explaining so politely and thoroughly, Vadian. I will consider using Codable.